# How to create a scheduled task from a Windows Service?

Tags: windows, go, nssm

I am trying to create a scheduled task from a Windows service.

The service runs as nt authority\system. If I open a command prompt as nt authority\system, I can create the scheduled task with:

```
C:\\Windows\\System32\\schtasks.exe /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /Create /SC ONCE /TN MyTaskNT1339 /TR C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\my.exe /ST 13:39
```

With this, once 1339 comes around, my.exe runs properly, so, I believe that all permissions are fine.

The service I am running is this Go block:

```
user, err := user.Current()
username := user.Username
cmd := exec.Command("C:\\Windows\\System32\\schtasks.exe", 
"/RU", 
username,//I have also tried "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM", "\"NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM\"", etc
"/Create",
    "/SC",
    "ONCE",
    "/TN",
    "MyTaskSched1320",
    "/TR",
    "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\my.exe", 
"/ST",
"13:20",

)
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
fmt.Println("run error")
fmt.Println(err.Error()) // this outputs "exit status 1"
}
fmt.Println("sched test service end")

}
```

Which is started as a service via nssm.

In addition to the "exit status 1" in the log, when trying to start the service with the above scheduled task block I get the error popup:
"Windows could not start the service_name service on Local Computer. The service did not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error. If the problem persists, contact your administrator."

If I change the cmd block in the service to simply:

```
cmd := exec.Command("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\my.exe",
```

the service will run my.exe as well, but not as a scheduled task.

It appears that you need to specify `/RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"` for a service to be created from a nt authority\system user.

I am using the EC2 Windows_Server-2022-English-Full-Base-2023.08.10 AMI.

Comment: Is this code block *all* that the service is supposed to do? I can see why Windows and NSSM think that it failed. Services are designed to start in the background and continue running. Also, it looks like you're trying to change the scheduler while you're still starting the service. If there's some kind of shared resource, you'd expect this to fail. This just isn't a normal scenario. A service can legitimately just sleep until 13:39. No need to involve the scheduler for that.

Comment: The actual service does a bunch more. The part that is failing is creating a scheduled task.

Basically, the service is a runner that does a bunch of our ops. One of the things we need to be able to do from it is create a scheduled task.

The above code block is just an attempt at isolating that problem. In the above I hardcoded the start time for simplicity.

>Also, it looks like you're trying to change the scheduler while you're still starting the service.

I am not sure I fully understand that. Do I need a block to keep running in addition to the schtasks when running with NSSM?

Comment: NSSM is a bit of a red herring, I think. The key thing here is that you're trying to run as a Windows Service process. NSSM tries to hide some of the necessities, but one of the things is that a Service should stick around and report its service ("RUNNING"). Even just sleeping for a while might help. But at that point, why not just sleep all the way? I understand 13:39 is hardcoded, but in general you can just sleep until you want to do something